# Is it possible to use the % type wild card with IN operator

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like

I'm currently analyzing string data and I want to view the count of specific words from a bunch of text.

I have something like these

```
SELECT
COUNT(text)
FROM review
WHERE text like "%hate%" or "%love%"
```

but it returns counts for only "%hate%". When I switched it with "%love%" first it returns only counts for "%love%". How do I write the query so that it will return the total counts for a series of words?

Comment: `WHERE text like '%hate%' or  text like '%love%'`

Comment: Every expression is 'self-contained'

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
SELECT    COUNT(text)
FROM review
WHERE text like "%hate%" or text like "%love%";
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I guess if I have to return records for say 10 words, I'll have to use the OR operator 9 times. I wish there was a way I can gather all my text without adding the OR operator every time.